# Proving a Trick to More Quickly Calculate N-Step Transition Probabilities

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

So, I have been working on a homework problem all day that asks me to prove that: $P^n= \Pi +Q^n$
where P is the transition matrix of a finite-state regular Markov Chain, $\Pi$ is a matrix whose rows are the stationary distribution of P, and $Q = P - \Pi$.

The fundamental relation that I have been attempting to show is that $(P-\Pi)^n=P^n-\Pi$. I'm not sure if there is a relevant matrix product property here that would allow me to establish this relation but I can't figure out how to proceed. Also, for those who have math backgrounds but not necessarily statistics backgrounds, the stationary distribution is just a left eigenvector with eigenvalue 1, and P is a stochastic matrix (rows summing to 1).

Originally, I was attempting to rewrite the matrix product relation in sigma notation and try to achieve some sort of simplification. I didn't find anything by doing that, so here is my most current attempt:

$P^n= \Pi +Q^n$

Substituting in for Q to get to the relation I referred to earlier:

$P^n=\Pi+(P-\Pi)^n$

$P^n-\Pi=(P-\Pi)^n$

Then, I use the property that the eigenvalue of $\Pi$ is 1 to rewrite P as $\Pi*P$.

$(\Pi*P-\Pi)^n=P^n-\Pi$

$\Pi^n*(P-1)^n=P^n-\Pi$

From here, I am unsure how to proceed but believe that this is a natural way to use the eigenvalue to alter the relation.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's customary here to show your thoughts and what you have tried. Have your followed up the eigenvector hint? Can you illustrate/explain why this is a 'trick' that aids in computation? Do you mean $\Pi$ instead of $Pi$? (If so, it's `\Pi` with dollar signs before and after.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and your comment! I did indeed mean $\Pi$ when I said Pi. Qualitatively, I tried rewriting the matrix products as a set of linear equations in sigma notation but got nothing out of it. I will consider how I can use the eigenvector hint and then edit my question to reflect the work that I have done.

Comment: I think I've found a solution if $\Pi$ raised to the power is itself. Is that true/can you direct me to a proof of some sort if so? Otherwise, I'm still stuck at the point in the question.

Comment: As explained in an answer below, $\Pi^2=\Pi$ is not enough but $P\Pi=\Pi P=\Pi^2=\Pi$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand matrix $\Pi$ to be:

$$
\Pi =   \begin{bmatrix}
        \pi_0 & \pi_1 & \cdots & \pi_m \\
        \pi_0 & \pi_1 & \cdots & \pi_m \\
        \cdots &  & & \\
        \pi_0 & \pi_1 & \cdots & \pi_m \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

The property of $\Pi$ that: $\;\Pi P = P\Pi = \Pi\;\Pi  = \Pi\;$ is easy to prove. We have

$$Q^n = (P-\Pi)^n$$

and if we expand that expression, using the above property we get much simplification (any term containing at least one factor of $\Pi$ reduces to $\pm\Pi$) and our expansion finishes up with the following terms:

\begin{align}
2^{n-1} & \;\text{ instances of } -\Pi \\
2^{n-1}-1 & \;\text{ instances of } \Pi \\
1 & \;\text{ instance of } P^n.
\end{align}

So we get

$$\Pi + Q^n = \Pi + (-\Pi + P^n) = P^n.$$

---

**Proof of above property:**

1. $\Pi P=\Pi$: this is part of the definition of a stationary distribution.
2. $P\Pi = \Pi$: the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of $P\Pi$ by matrix multiplication is:

$$\sum_{k} p_{ik}\cdot\pi_j = \pi_j\sum_{k} p_{ik} = \pi_j = (i,j)^{th} \text{ entry of } \Pi.$$

3. $\Pi\;\Pi = \Pi$: the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of $\Pi\;\Pi$ by matrix multiplication is:

$$\sum_{k} \pi_{k}\cdot\pi_j = \pi_j\sum_{k} \pi_{k} = \pi_j = (i,j)^{th} \text{ entry of } \Pi.$$

Comment: Clears up a question I had about this. +1

Comment: I think you're initial statement that you say is easy to prove is actually the crux of my trouble with the proof. Given the information that you provided, I understand how to solve the problem. However, I don't understand generally why it is true that I can move the $\Pi$ in the first relation or why it is fair to exchange a P for a $\Pi$ in the later part of the statement. Could you clarify what the easy proof is, or at least hint at some intuition behind why that's true?

Comment: @ConnorRoberts I've added the proof of the property. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Mick! You're proof makes perfect sense to me and I really appreciate your taking the time out to explain it. I'm concurrently enrolled in linear algebra and stochastics, so I'm a little behind in terms of ability to reason generally about matrix arithmetic. Using the sigma notation to reason generally about the product entries seems to be a useful tool that I need to keep in mind in the future. Thanks again and I've marked your answer as a solution!

Comment: @Mick A One last thing. When I did the count of interaction terms (excluding the end terms of P and Q raised to the n), I got that there would be 2 raised to the n-1 minus 2 total terms in the series, rather than that number of positive and negative respectively. Clearly, the proof still works in the same way as long as the terms cancel, but I was curious if I was  making a mistake. Also, how do you raise a number to an expression such as $n-1$ on this site? I counted by just raising to the number of slots that could be either P or Q then subtracting the end terms.

Comment: @Cmanbst A concrete example: $$(P-\Pi)^3=PPP - PP\Pi - P\Pi P + P\Pi\;\Pi - \Pi PP + \Pi P\Pi + \Pi\;\Pi P - \Pi\;\Pi\;\Pi \\ = P^3 - (2^{3-1})\Pi + (2^{3-1}-1)\Pi \\ = P^3-\Pi.$$ For exponents use `a^{bc}` for $a^{bc}$.

Answer (score 0):

$Comment:$  Related computation in R, demonstrating the eigenvector method
of finding the limiting distribution of a Markov chain with a
finite state space that consists of a single intercommunicating class.
The limiting distribution is also the stationary distribution.

Note: This is $not$ an answer to the original question, but may be
related to a question in a comment. I suppose a similar computation
can be done in Matlab.

$P$ is a $6 \times 6$ transition matrix; it could be defined in
a single row, but the entry format used makes it easier to read.

```
 P  = (1/40)*matrix(c( 0, 20,  5,  5,  5,  5,
                       8,  0,  8,  8,  8,  8,
                      10,  0,  0, 10, 10, 10,
                      10,  0, 10,  0, 10, 10,
                      10,  0, 10, 10,  0, 10,
                      10,  0, 10, 10, 10,  0), nrow=6, byrow=T)
 P
 ##      [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
 ## [1,] 0.00  0.5 0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125
 ## [2,] 0.20  0.0 0.200 0.200 0.200 0.200
 ## [3,] 0.25  0.0 0.000 0.250 0.250 0.250
 ## [4,] 0.25  0.0 0.250 0.000 0.250 0.250
 ## [5,] 0.25  0.0 0.250 0.250 0.000 0.250
 ## [6,] 0.25  0.0 0.250 0.250 0.250 0.000

  g = eigen(t(P))$vectors[,1]      # t=transpose for row (not column) eigenvector
  lim.dist = g/sum(g)              # to make vector sum to 1
  lim.dist = as.numeric(lim.dist)  # kill needless complex number notation
```

R prints a matrix of eigenvectors in decreasing order of moduli, we want
the one with the largest modulus, hence the notation `[,1]` above (to retrieve the first column of that matrix).
In general, eigenvectors may have complex elements; this one has
only real elements. The command `as.numeric` simplifies the
output.

```
 g
 ## [1] -0.4719292+0i -0.2359646+0i -0.4247363+0i -0.4247363+0i
 ## [5] -0.4247363+0i -0.4247363+0i

 lim.dist
 ## 0.19607843 0.09803922 0.17647059 0.17647059 0.17647059 0.17647059
```

Check that we have the correct answer so that $\lambda P = \lambda$.
[Also, $P^8$ has all rows (very nearly) equal to $\lambda.$]

```
 lim.dist %*% P   # '%*%' denotes matrix multiplication in R
 ##      [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
 ## 0.1960784 0.09803922 0.1764706 0.1764706 0.1764706 0.1764706
```